# Error - No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: 'smtp.office365.com'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Revisando el tema de envío de correos, usando c# mvc, pero me surge el siguiente error, para resolver la excepción he revisado varios ejemplos tanto de esta plataforma, como en otras paginas que tocan el tema, sin embargo no lo he podido resolver.

Esto es parte de lo que realice:

```
 using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587))
                    {
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario@nombredel correo.mail.onmicrosoft.com", "contraseña", "dominio");
                        smtp.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
                        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.Send(message);
                        message.Dispose();
                        smtp.Dispose();
                    };
```

Sin embargo el error que me indica es en esta parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es parte de la configuración que tengo dentro de mi WebConfig:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="xxxx@xxxxxx" deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.office365.com" 
             port="587" password="mi contraseña de mi correo" userName="usuario@xxxx"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings></system.net>
```

Intente ingresar con las 3 configuraciones que tiene outlook:

outlook.office365.com --> usando los puertos 995 y 993 también ocupe smtp.office365.com --> usando el puerto 587.

Por lo que realmente he revisado y depurado pero no se puede realizar el envío, los correos que ocupo en este desarrollo no son personales.

Igualmente les agradecería de sus comentarios y/o opiniones.

Gracias.

Comment: No-respuesta: El servicio smtp.office.com por el 587 usa STARTTLS pero es sin SSL prendido. Son cosas diferentes. Sobre el error, tu servidor es incapaz de resolver ese dominio y no sabemos qué servidores DNS estás usando. :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Entiendo revisare el DNS, gracias por su cometario.